# Creating image thumbnails to be loaded into tableview from files in app directory

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, thumbnails

I need some help for a problem which I can't solve but I think I am close to the solution. Here is it:

In a version of my app, I was able to populate a tableview (in `CellforRowAtIndexPath`) with images taken from the `Assetlibrary` using the following 2 lines:

```
ALAsset someAsset = [theAssets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[someAsset thumbnail]]];
```

Now, I am trying to read image files from the directory and stored in an `NSMutableArray`. I can see the filenames when I `NSLog` the `NSMutableArray`. But how do I now cause the files to be converted into images and displayed in my tableview in the same way I did why using the `Assetlibrary`? I have tried several times, but the app either crashes or it does not show the image thumbnails in the table view. For example, this statement does not display the image but the app does not crash:

```
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self.listTable objectAtIndex:0]];
```

When I setImage in the next line, it doesn't work. Someone please help!

UPDATED: The contents of self.listable when I NSLog it is something like this: "19-10-25 276-10-12.jpg",
    "19-10-37 276-10-12.jpg",
    "19-10-54 276-10-12.jpg",
    "19-10-65 276-10-12.mov", etc.

When I NSLog my documents directory, it is: /var/mobile/Applications/8CB1368A-AAE2-4815-BD26-A7B7C8536193/Documents.

Comment: I update the question with the contents of self.listTable and also my document directory. How do I make my filenames to have a complete path? I want to be able to create the image with every file in the listTable array. How do I write or modify my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps can only `imageWithContentsOfFile` for files located within the app's sandbox (e.g. in `Documents`, the bundle, etc.) If these files are located in your `Documents` folder, you get the full path via:

```
NSString *documentsFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageFullPath   = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFilename];
```

You can then use that in `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

---

**Update:**

You asked:

> my `directoryContents` is an `NSArray`; how do I convert it to `NSString` and then `[documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent ...]` and store each fullpath in the `NSMutableArray`?

You might do something like:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager   = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *filenames           = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSMutableArray *paths        = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[filenames count]];

for (NSString *filename in filenames)
{
    [paths addObject:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
}

NSLog(@"%s filenames = %@", __FUNCTION__, filenames);
NSLog(@"%s paths = %@", __FUNCTION__, paths);
```

Comment: But where do I obtain the "imageFilename" you used in your second line of code? I tried something similar previously but the images don't show up hence my confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is a filename and I have one more step to solve the problem. I get the filenames in an NSArray like this:  NSArray *directoryContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil. I also get the document directory like this: /var/mobile/Applications/8CB1368A-AAE2-4815-BD26-A7B7C8536193/Documents. My final goal is to be able to derive an NSMutableString for each filename like: /var/mobile/Applications/8CB1368A-AAE2-4815-BD26-A7B7C8536193/Documents/19-10-25 276-10-12.jpg", etc. I have tried different approaches but I am still missing something please help.

Comment: my directoryContents is an NSArray; how do I convert it to NSString and then [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent ...] and store each fullpath in the NSMutableArray? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Paulo see my revised answer.

Comment: thanks a LOT! Now I just made the right call in my tableview method and its working!